# Are there any snippet software app for windows user?

Tags: html, css, windows

I'm a web designer, and I'm used to collect snippets of code I find in the internet.
I found `snippely` as a great snippet app but it doesn't have export or import features when I'm going to different working station.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Opera browser](http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/642/) which has a built in facility for snippets (or notes as they are called) and these can be synchronised to any computer you have running Opera.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a suggestion for tool some might think is over reaching, but it could be the best solution if it's useful to you *and* serves a few other needs, too.

I like to use [EverNote](http://www.evernote.com/) for things like this.

It has a very good web client, and compiled apps for PC, Mac, iPhone, and Android. So the text you collect is likely to be available wherever you are.

EverNote will also capture audio, pictures, and rich text. It's a great note taking tool, and it's free for accounts uploading less than 40MB per month of data. Paid accounts get more capacity and SSL, some collaboration features and more.

Answer (score 1):

A [pastebin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin) is a web application which allows its users to upload snippets of text, usually samples of source code, for public viewing.

You can pick one from this [list of pastebin apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_pastebins) that needs a sign-up so that you can track your posts. Typically, these apps don't require a sign-up and they generate a random URL for your snippet that you can use & share.

Answer (score 0):

Lifehacker's [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows) is the only standalone one I know of. It's free, open source, and easy to use.

Also, if you have a background in programming, [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) might be a viable option. Texter has a GUI so thats probably your best choice.

Personally, I use vim for coding, so I use a combination of snipMate and [sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) for writing code. I used to use Textmate when I had a Mac, but when I went to Windows, I used [E Text Editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) for a bit. It's a feature for feature port of Textmate to Windows, and if you love Textmate, you'll be right at home.

But since I've discovered vim and sparkup/zen coding, I've had very little use for snippets anymore. It' so much more efficient to use these instead of snippets. Sparkup is only for vim, but [zen coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) is available for pretty much any editor under the sun.